# Throw bad_cast exc without hierarchy

Tags: c++, exception

is it possible to throw a bad_cast exception without making any hierarchy or new classes different from C?
The main() cannot be edited and the only thing that can be edited is C class. Also I cannot throw bad_cast explicitly.

```
class C{
    private:
        ...

    public:
        void f(){
        ...
        }
};


int main () {
    C c;
    c.f();

}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: *"I cannot throw bad_cast explicitly."*  Why can't you?

Comment: @DrewDormann: Presumably because this is a puzzle, not a real programming problem, and allowing that would make it trivial to solve.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a programming puzzle. This type of question would be more appropriate on Programming Puzzles and Code Golf Stack Exchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The main() cannot be edited and the only thing that can be edited is C class. Also I cannot throw bad_cast explicitly.

Given those constraints, define a polymorphic class nested inside `C`, and attempt to cast that to something unrelated (such as `C` itself):

```
class C{
    private:
        struct X {virtual ~X(){}};

    public:
        void f(){
            X x;
            dynamic_cast<C&>(x);
        }
};

int main () {
    C c;
    c.f();
}
```

Note that this is likely to give a compiler warning, since it is smart enough to work out that the cast can never succeed.

If you also include the constraint that you can't make any new classes, then it's impossible. `bad_cast` is only thrown by the language itself when using `dynamic_cast`; that can only be applied to polymorphic types, and there are no polymorphic types available.

Comment: Thanks so much for your advice!! That is the solution! Of course this was a puzzle, not a real programming problem!

Comment: @RobertoMolinaro: Well, I thought about this, but I realized it would not satisfy the constraint "*without making any hierarchy or new classes different from C*". Here there is a new class `X` different from `C`

Comment: @AndyProwl: Indeed; hence the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you cannot.

`dynamic_cast` works for polymorphic class types only, and no built-in type of the C++ core language is a polymorphic class type.

So as long as you can't define any new polymorphic classes (nor `#include` the definition of other, already existing polymorphic classes), or can't invoke another function that does see those definitions (which one should probably regard as cheating), there is no way you can get a `bad_cast` exception.

Also, there is no core language construct other than `dynamic_cast` that throws the `std::bad_cast` exception. So the answer to your question:

> is it possible to throw a bad_cast exception without making any hierarchy or new classes different from C?

Is "**No**".